# height: 100% for anchor tag inside table cell keeping vertical-align

Tags: html, css

How to align vertically "Foo" Between "Bar" and "Baz" as it do automatically without anchor? I can't use [line-height hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10437784/697625), 'cause I want to allow link text to expand cell significantly.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="link-wrap">
       <a class="link" href="#">
         Foo
       </a>
    </td>
   <td>Bar<br>Baz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.link-wrap {
  height: 100%;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  background: #afa;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Sandbox](http://jsbin.com/oqaka3/62/)

Comment: Sidebar. There's a "Related" section. Use it.

Comment: I assure you, there's no open solution to this problem per se.

Answer (score 3):

You want this? [jsbin 1](http://jsbin.com/oqaka3/63/)

Solution is simple: don't use a `display: block` with a height. The height is the problem here.

When you want to apply the color to the whole td, then apply the color also to the td and not to an inner element.

---

**UPDATE**: [jsbin 2](http://jsbin.com/oqaka3/67/)

Just some *magic*. What I've done is transforming the `<a>` tag in a table (with css; so it has all it's properties) and I've created a `<span>` in it with `vertical-align: middle;` and `display: table-cell;`. So it's basically a table in a table. So, the pseudo-table is an `<a>`: clickable in all its space.

Comment: No, the whole cell space should be clickable.

Comment: @quasiyoke You maybe want to report a bug for webkit?

Comment: me too :) but I can't mark this as "accepted" if it doesn't work in most popular browser. Outer cell has unremovable top and bottom padding.

Comment: @quasiyoke I just noticed that, when I change the height to NUMBER_OF_ROWSem, it works... :o (of the a)

Comment: It's now 2018 and this still doesn't work in Chrome!