# Text vertical align inside an anchor (<a>) tag

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, text-align

Sample demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ES225/)

```html
<h3><a class="myButton" href="#">Tell Me More &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-2x"></i></a></h3>
```

As you can see in my JSFiddle, the text *Tell Me More* is not vertically center aligned.

How can I do that?

Comment: you have 6px padding on top and bottom, but both elements don't have the same height, a quick fix to that is to put a line-height on the text container (anchor tag in that example) of the height of the icon you have on the right, This will center the text probably. http://jsfiddle.net/ES225/4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical align middle on an inline-block anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437643/vertical-align-middle-on-an-inline-block-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ES225/28/)

Add this CSS content:

```
.fa
{
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: thanks . it works.  but it won't let me add `MARGIN-TOP` on `myButton` class selector. What i mean is **MARGIN-TOP** don't work.

Comment: @Unknownymous : I have updated some codes on my second fiddle. see that above fiddle. margin-top will work now... with margin-top http://jsfiddle.net/ES225/8/ and without margin-top http://jsfiddle.net/ES225/10/

Answer (score 26):

You should use new CSS 3 features, in this case [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
a,button {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex; /* CSS3 */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical align */
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontal align */
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Testing 1,2,3</span></a>
    <button><span>Testing 1,2,3</span></button>
```

It is as simple as that.

All browsers support it. See [caniuse.com/#search=flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Also check out the free and excellent course [flexbox.io/](http://flexbox.io/). He is the best teacher at this.

Also check out [css-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), also new in CSS 3.

Comment: As soon as the text wraps, it will be left aligned in this sample

Answer (score 0):

```
.myButton {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.fa {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Oh sorry, right now margin works even if you apply them to the `.myButton`.